# Error when trying to evolve Feebas to Milotic in Pokemon Go

Tags: pokemon-go

I keep getting the message, “Error” when I try to evolve my Milotic from Feebas. I have 100 candies and my buddy Feebas walked 20km with me. Yet still the error message. I tried closing out and logging in again to no avail. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried evolving Feebas while it's your buddy? If so, does it still get the error?

Comment: Yep. Ultimately, I unbuddied and re-buddied her and powered her up, replenished some candy, and the error eventually went away. She is now evolved. Seems it was just a temporary glitch of some kind.

Comment: You should add that as an answer @Papachu31 in case anyone else has that issue.

Answer (score 3):

In case it may help someone, I was experiencing the same issue as OP when attempting to evolve my Feebas.  After finding/reading this post I unbuddied Feebas, powered her up a few times (although I suspect this part to be unnecessary), and was then immediately able to evolve her w/o error.  Note that she was *not* set as my buddy when successfully evolved.

[image: Milot☆Ⓤ92.5%]

Answer (score 1):

As [Papachu31](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/399722/error-when-trying-to-evolve-feebas-to-milotic-in-pokemon-go#comment561491_399722) states

> I unbuddied and re-buddied her and powered her up, replenished some candy, and the error eventually went away.

The `error eventually went away` portion might be the biggest clue.
My personal experiences with no evolve issues has been resolved either over time, restarting the game or even clearing out the games cache from the phone settings menu.

if the problem persists across phone reboots, cache clearing and time. Try on someones else's phone or contact Niantic (especially if it takes longer than a few days). One time, they actually looked at my account and gave back a item I lost trying to accomplish something and to "try now".